# Не могу считать объект json

Tags: java

```html
atabase, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\Senko_KL\IdeaProjects\outputjsondatabase) libraryTable took 14 ms 
2019-12-05 15:30:16,232 [2245205]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=outputjsondatabase, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\Senko_KL\IdeaProjects\outputjsondatabase) SvnFileUrlMappingImpl took 14 ms 
2019-12-05 15:33:08,472 [2417445]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=outputjsondatabase, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\Senko_KL\IdeaProjects\outputjsondatabase) DBNavigator.Project.Settings took 19 ms 
2019-12-05 15:39:47,919 [2816892]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=outputjsondatabase, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\Senko_KL\IdeaProjects\outputjsondatabase) ExternalProjectModuleManager took 20 ms 
2019-12-05 15:49:11,946 [3380919]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2019-12-05 15:49:11,950 [3380923]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile C:\Users\Senko_KL\IdeaProjects\outputjsondatabase 
2019-12-05 15:49:13,911 [3382884]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened 
2019-12-05 15:49:13,911 [3382884]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -  COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 1964 ms: 0 min 1sec 
2019-12-05 15:49:14,488 [3383461]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/lib/tools.jar 
2019-12-05 15:49:14,593 [3383566]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-12-05 15:49:14,593 [3383566]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-12-05 15:49:14,593 [3383566]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-12-05 15:49:23,717 [3392690]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2019-12-05 15:49:23,720 [3392693]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile C:\Users\Senko_KL\IdeaProjects\outputjsondatabase 
2019-12-05 15:49:23,846 [3392819]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -  COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 147 ms: 0 min 0sec 
2019-12-05 15:49:23,852 [3392825]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened 
2019-12-05 15:49:24,329 [3393302]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/lib/tools.jar 
2019-12-05 15:49:24,393 [3393366]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-12-05 15:49:24,393 [3393366]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-12-05 15:49:24,393 [3393366]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-12-05 15:49:47,336 [3416309]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2019-12-05 15:49:47,339 [3416312]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile C:\Users\Senko_KL\IdeaProjects\outputjsondatabase 
2019-12-05 15:49:49,119 [3418092]   INFO - .server.BuildMessageDispatcher - Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение 
java.io.IOException: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
 at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:247)
 at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1147)
 at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
 at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2019-12-05 15:49:49,141 [3418114]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -  COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 1818 ms: 0 min 1sec 
2019-12-05 15:49:49,158 [3418131]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened 
2019-12-05 15:49:49,610 [3418583]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/lib/tools.jar 
2019-12-05 15:49:49,675 [3418648]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-12-05 15:49:49,675 [3418648]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-12-05 15:49:49,675 [3418648]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

При считывании объекта json появляется исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    private static final String fileName = "C:/Users/Senko_KL/IdeaProjects/inputjsondatabase/dbFile.json";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас где-то есть данные вида [], а вы говорите, что их надо читать как {}

Comment: У вас json структура в файле не верная, исправьте, можете проверить данные с файла с онлайн сервисов для работы json, например один из них http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"у вас где-то есть данные вида [], а вы говорите, что их надо читать как {}" просто надо использовать JSONArray вместо JsonObject

```html
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(fileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка в том, что InputStreamReader возвращает массив байт.
Попробуйте вот что:

```
public class Main {
    private static final String fileName = "C:/Users/Senko_KL/IdeaProjects/inputjsondatabase/dbFile.json";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(fileName)
                .getFile())) {
            // read the json file


            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

            // Do what you want here, example:

            System.out.println(jsonObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Появляется исключение Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, хот я путь указан правильно

Comment: в какой строке Exception? было бы лучше если бы вы скидывали логи полнее

Comment: В строке где FileReader

Comment: отредактировал, попробуйте и скиньте все логи которые у вас будут сюда

Comment: добавил логи, ....

Comment: У вас программа не может принять от хоста корректно файл судя по логам